# Monitor data usage on iPhone connected to WiFi

Tags: iphone, vpn, wifi

My iPhone seems to download huge amounts of data according to Google WiFi stats. The last 30 days this was almost 1TB:

[image: data usage of iPhone last 30 days]

I can't pinpoint it to 1 specific app, my Photos library is only about 350 GB, so that couldn't be it for instance. Is there any app or tool that lets me monitor the actual endpoints my phone is connecting to? (like a custom VPN that passes trough all data but just keeps logs of the domains)

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, two options.

1. Debookee on macOS, this allows to log http/s traffic and DNS requests from remote (iOS) devices in your network.

https://debookee.com

2. Charles for iOS, this allows to see the network connections/traffic directly on the iOS device.

https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/ios/